# Is there a limit on the length of a question?

Tags: discussion, character-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please notify me of the 30,000 character limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25066)

Is there a limit on the length of a question/post on the SO sites?

I was posting to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29136/featured-articles-on-so) and claim there is no limit. I don't see an explicit limit. Is there a limit?

The tag [`character-length`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-length) seems to not have anything definitive.

Comment: Dup http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/please-increase-the-maximum-allowed-length-for-answers

Comment: I guess there's no appeal. I see answers that indicate a 40k character limit, and answers that indicate a 30k limit. I find the closing of this question against the spirit of contributors attempting to add value to the site.

Comment: Then test with 30001 and 40001 characters in a post and see where you end up. Try it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Answer (score 1):

**30,000 characters**

[Assuming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Size_comparisons) an average word length of 5, plus a space, that's about **5000 words**. [Assuming](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=608972) the average page of a novel has 250 words, it's the equivalent in length to **20 pages of a novel**).

Source: on the post ["Please increase the maximum allowed length for answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/please-increase-the-maximum-allowed-length-for-answers), Jeff Atwood [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/please-increase-the-maximum-allowed-length-for-answers/14142#14142):

> If you "need" to post more than 30k
>   chars, that's probably symptomatic of
>   other problems.

Comment: This question is a dupe, so there is no need to answer, since it's already been answered.

Comment: My cite says 30k, your dupe says 40k. I would say that it's not a settled question and feel this question has been closed without considering the fact that a user can't really find a definitive answer. This question was a chance to get that answer and is the reason I opened it.