# Any chance of long form articles getting the SO/SE treatment?

Tags: feature-request, blog, article

I checked out these questions:
  [Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/)
  [Can I post “how to” articles here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18864/)
  [What is the etiquette for posting an article?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24608/)
  [Featured Articles on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29136/)

As the SO system becomes easier and better to use, I think SO'izing other things could have real benefits, especially since SO/SE is now going to become the owner of many communities, and they won't necessarily be affiliated with additional sites providing these features.

In particular, I take part in other communities where an article is not a Wiki and it has a single owner (this is good for things like real articles, demos and worked examples), the discussion below it is hard to follow (if it is a blog-post-style article), never threaded and doesn't allow comments on comments - and they never have voting.

In other cases, the article may have a thread attached to it in a traditional (barf) discussion forum, and it's linked, but you can't tell how active it is, and there isn't voting.

Any chance, we get an SO treatment of this?  (i.e. kind of like an SO'ized blog?  or editor-managed site?)

I'm thinking in particular of SQLServerCentral (which has an SE site, but it's not integrated - so they have forums and articles on their regular site, too - but it's painful to use that traditional stuff).

I'm not saying this needs to be a direct peer of the Q&A on the same host, but some of the SO/SE communities may benefit from articles on another host - like ask.actionfigures.com for Q&A and articles.actionfigures.com for user-submitted pricing analysis of Christmas Yodas over the years and blog.actionfigures.com being the "official" blog.

Answer (score 1):

There are some very fundamental differences between how SO is designed and used and how people interact with blogs and article type content.  There are a lot of good ideas in SO that are well implemented and could become part of a reasonable blog CMS, but I doubt very much that Stackoverflow LLC will pursue this area.

There are a variety of [stackoverflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones), many of which are open source, that may be suited to your needs with some modification.  Some of the authors may even be interested in branching out and differentiating their product from StackOverflow's product.

Your ideas has a great deal of merit, as others have already implemented blog post and blog comment rating systems for the major blog CMS packages.  You might look there as well, since there are a lot of features that blogs support that no current SO clone supports (such as image uploading, wysiwig editing, trackbacks and pings, etc).

Comment: My point was that now that the Stack platform will be building additional community-suggested communities which will not have outside "official" owners who would link in additional functionality, it may be time to work on providing that functionality to their communities.  If the communities have their own identity, there will probably be a "blog" with the official direction for that community, just like there is for SO.  But notice how SO's blog is very traditional with comments hidden away and no voting (on posts or comments).

Comment: @Cade: The blog comments aren't hidden away, just hidden on the main page (like they are on SO, too).  A blog can have different categories, and it might make sense to publish some things on the SE blog (it's merging with the SO blog) for the various new SE sites.  However, the Engine just doesn't seem work well for [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/), and individual sites/communities certainly can and will sprout up blogs specific to their needs.

Comment: @The Cat I think it's becoming obvious that the SO engine works better for dicussion than most forums and blog comments.  The Hot feature also shows what people are talking about, which may be better for blogs and articles with high interactivity.  To be clear, I'm not talking about changing the Q&A side, I'm talking about an expansion into another community space using similar principles which have proven so successful to apply to single-author long form with comments.

Comment: @Cade: That might be worth considering (not doing, just considering doing) in a year or two.  There is so much going on with AFO right now to branch out quickly, IMHO.

Comment: @The Cat - It's abundantly clear that the whole thing has fragmented very quickly (just looking at the number of profiles that get pulled in when I go to different sites) and hopefully SE 2.0 will start to tie things back together.